# Send data from front end to backend node js using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In frontend script I have:

```
function loadContent(){
  var count = 0;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/getMore", true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
  if(this.status == 200){
    data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

I'm trying to pass variable 'count' to the backend in my node js like this:

```
router.get("/getMore", async function(req, res){
  count = req.params.count;
});
```

I can't seem to get past that. How do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the count and its value in your url as route parameters. You can concatenate it with your url.

```
var url = 'http://foo.bar/getMore/count/' + count;
xhr.open('GET', url);
```

then in your node.js backend, assuming you are using express, you have to define your route parameters:

```
app.get('/getMore/count/:countVal', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.countVal);
});
```

More about route params here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html